# Desired response of PI controller in motor vector controller

Tags: motor, control-system, pid-controller

In vector control (field-oriented control) of motors (specifically induction motors), a rotating reference frame is attached to the rotor flux to give "DC" values in the current controller. This enables PI control to be used (which is not possible, or at least not ideal, with continuously varying signals, e.g. sinusoidal waveforms in a static reference frame).

The gains of the PI controller can be tuned to give a good response to changes in current demand. My question is: how does the response of the current controller (level of damping) affect the torque response of the drive?

This is probably application-specific, but are there any general rules, like "always under-damp since the mechanical system has a slower response" or something like that (this is just a hypothetical example).

Comment: It should be noted that this question is actually "Off topic" as it's not about electronics design. This sort of question is more about control theory and DSP and might be better off in the DSP stack exchange site

Comment: I am interested in how the control theory relates to this specific application in electrical engineering.

Comment: Controlling electric motors is most definitely electrical engineering.

Comment: The motor's parameters, and therefore it's mechanical damping effect, must normally be modelled or tested in-system (like what TI's Instaspin does) and is a critical part of the control system design.

Comment: You should have some bandwidth requirements somewhere. General rule of thumb is as you move from the voltage loop (the FOC) to the speed (any maybe to a position) the bandwidth drops by a decade. Switching freq at 10kHz -> current loop bandwidth around 1kHz, speed at 100Hz etc... specific PI will be against stability requirements. AND this needs to be modelled!

Answer (score 1):

In control system theory, "is a critically damped response ideal" is relative. Critically damped systems ARE ideal, only if you are looking for the fastest possible rise time with zero overshoot and fastest possible settling time (due to there being no ripple).

The Clark/Park transforms in Field Oriented Control are what provide DC style signals you refer to.

If the application of the control system favours very fast reaction speed (for example, a load is added to a spinning device which slows it down, the ability to return to the required/set speed is what the control system would do) and cares little about overshoot would have very little damping, and high proportional gain in order to get in this case, the "ideal" response. That is, the designers do not care if the speed of the spinning device goes over the set point, and oscillates a little bit before settling back to the correct speed with the load now on it.

If your device is a medical robot arm that does surgery on people, you would very much like a damped response, perhaps "critically damped" is too difficult to achieve, so the designers would allow for a nice, slow, safe control of the robotic arm movement - perhaps in reaction to the movement of a haptic feedback device operated by a doctor. Overshoot in this case might cut people in strange places, so is undesirable! Control systems are very arbitrary in exactly what they are "controlling" and what the inputs

Comment: I understand that the response of this drive system as a whole, i.e. torque or speed, depending on the control objective, is subjective and application-specific. I am specifically referring to the current controller response. Maybe what my question boils down to is 'how does the response of the current controller affect the response of the drive?' (Perhaps oscillations from an under-damped response in the current controller is damped by the slower response of the mechanical system to produce a faster torque response? Just speculation)

Comment: Well, you could design a circuit with discrete components, implementing a PI controller using Op-amps and passive components, to have a fully electrical based controller for whatever you wanted. For example, you may have a hot-pluggable panel for loads such as some spotlights, and a power system using a PI controller that uses adjustable voltage as an output, to control (to reach the set point) current which might need to be at a particular level. I'm just making stuff up, but yeah there are plenty of examples of control systems made out of electronics.

Comment: @DaveWinterborne see above comment. The response of a lot of regulator ICs is indicative of 2nd order control systems, where the voltage is controlled and shows signs of overshoot etc when starting up, or reacting to load changes

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow the point you are making in your last two comments

Comment: @DaveWinterborne I was giving examples of other areas where control theory could be used in analog electronics, but I now think you are specifically asking about the use of PI controllers for FOC??

Comment: Yes, I'm interested specifically in FOC.

Comment: @DaveWinterborne well, current control allows you to control the speed of the rotor, so anything that might impact the speed of the FOC'd motor output can be adjusted for like any other controllable device, with the PI control. The error signal might be the flux angle, or the rotor position itself. What exactly do you want to know? the original question was a little vague especially the last paragraph..

Comment: Edited the question to reflect my thoughts in my first comment on your answer.

Comment: So there are typically two or more control loops, a current (torque) control loop and an outer speed and/or position control loop.  The more bandwidth you can get from the current loop, the more you can push the performance of the output loop(s).  So a fast underdamped response for the current loop with acceptable phase margin is OK for the inner current loop unless the application is very sensitive to torque ripple, in which case you would want to damp it.